# Cannont Update control in WPF custom control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have created a custom control which holds a button in it. The button is styled, so as to hold a grid with two rows, an image in the first and a TextBlock in the second. I have written an Event Handler for the custom control. When the mouse enters the path of the object the MouseEnter event fires, where I try to change the TextBlock's FontSize and Foreground color, however the control does not update. In contrast, I have tried to modify an regular TextBlock's(not part a custom control and controltemplate) properties, and they update correctly, on the fly.

What am I missing here?? Here is the code for the event handler:

```
private void ThemeButton_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    InitializeProperties();

    TextElement.FontSize = 16;
    TextElement.Text = "new text";
    TextElement.Foreground = Brushes.Red;

    TextBlock element = MainWindow.FindChild<TextBlock>(MainWindow.StartWindow, "textField");
    element.Text = "new text for regular textblock";
    element.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
}
```

InitializeProperties is a methid that initializes TextElement(typeof TextBlock) and ImageElement(typeof Image) properties. They are not null. The properties are just regular .NET properties.

Answer (score 0):

wow...my problem actually was that the Properties(TextElement and ImageElemenet) were pointing to the elements in the template(custom control) and not to the elements that actually got rendered in the Window...

Remember, when searching for elements, always start your search after rendering is complete(i.e. start search when a user action fires an event or something similar) so that the elements get into the Visual Tree!!